# in vscode, pygame wont import but it is installed and is working in the windows console ,and the python app thing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame

im very new to code in general so this could be a stupid beginner problem ive searched for things but i couldnt find something useful for me

under Problems is the message: **Import "pygame" could not be resolved**

[image: here is a image]

Comment: Restart vscode and first check if pygame is installed by `pygame --version` in cmd then open vscode.

Comment: yes it is it is working in console

Comment: You might need to choose which version of python VS Code is using. See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56675396/2280890) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69607385/2280890)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pip show pygame` to view the package installed location.

And check whether the installation location is consistent with the version corresponding to the selected Python interpreter.

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. "ctrl+shift+P" and change the python interpreter.
2. If you don't want to change the interpreter, you can use `pip -t flodername pygame #flodername is your used python package location`. Install the pygame package to the specified directory

Answer (score 0):

First, try restarting your computer or vs code

Use this command in your vs code terminal if the above doesn't work:

```
pip uninstall pygame
```

Then reinstall pygame using:

```
pip install pygame
```

If this also does not work then follow these steps:

1. Go to the scripts folder of python.
2. Open `command prompt` or `Powershell` in the script folder.
3. Use this:

   C:\python34\scripts> python -m pip install pygame

Done

Answer (score 0):

As an Anaconda user, I found my packages were being installed to `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`, which Visual Studio Code was not picking up on.

With the Pylance extension installed, open Settings (`File > Preferences > Settings`, or `Ctrl+,`)

At the top, beside `Workspace`, choose `User`

Under `Extensions > Pylance`, scroll until you find `Python › Analysis: Extra Paths` and select `Add item`.

Type in the path to which packages are being stored (in this case, `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`)

Click `OK` and after a couple moments, you should see something like the below image (i.e, the path is included in the list of paths).

[image: Python › Analysis: Extra Paths - Additional import search resolution paths - C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages]

Finally, your Python file should have picked up on the changes, but if not, reload it or VS Code. If nothing else, add another path that packages are being saved to or change your Python Interpreter. Using another virtual environment's interpreter wouldn't be very helpful, after all.

I may be late, but I hope this helped.